# public_activity and rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with public_activity gem under Rails 4. I've installed this gem correctly next i type rails g public_activity:migration and rake db:migrate. In the next step i add

```
include PublicActivity::Model
tracked
```

to my post model and generate controller activities with index action.
My Activities controller:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
  end
end
```

View for it:

```
<h1>Friend's Activities</h1>
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <%= activity.inspect %>
<% end %>
```

And the route is:

```
resources :activities
```

And when i gone to `http://localhost:3000/activities` i have error:

```
`attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one.
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4):

I guess your problem is your model has attr_accessible which is extracted as a gem after rails 4. If you love to see attr_accessible in models then add

```
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

to your Gemfile.

https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes more more documentation

If you want to follow rails4 way then here is the article to read:
http://rubyjunction.us/no-more-attr-accessible-in-ruby-on-rails-4

Comment: But the problem is that no one of my models have attr_accessible.
I have this app on github so if you could look to my models and help me to do this it will be great.https://github.com/MatUrbanski/Bloggers

Comment: @MateuszUrbański public_activity gem uses attr_accessible here https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity/blob/master/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record/activity.rb#L19

Comment: Thank's for reply, i used protected_attributes gem and everything working fine but i stil don't know how to do it to work to follow rails4 way...

Comment: please clarify whts the problem you are facing as you mentioned `attr_accessible is extracted out of ....` gone

Comment: Thank's for help everyone but i decide to build my own activity system in rails to fully work with rails 4.

Comment: We also developed our own, its a mixture of activity_log and papertrail. it works fine, We have a plan to extract as a gem in near future.

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of the public_activity gem has a check for the active record version to support rails 4, but it seems that is not yet on rubygems. I was able to get past this error by using the github version

In my gemfile:

> gem 'public_activity', github: 'pokonski/public_activity'

I then restarted the server and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that public_activity gem only check for rails version when its setting attr_accessible. If you are using earlier version then Rails 4, it will include it. I've submitted issue to [github/public_activity/128](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity/issues/128). I believe in future release they will resolve it.

For now my workaround is to create config/initializers/public_activity.rb

```
PublicActivity::Activity.class_eval do
    attr_accessible :key, :owner, :parameters, :recipient, :trackable
end
```